# Bug with Completeness Score (Personal Statement) on Careers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, profile-page

Currently, my completeness score on my SO careers profile is incorrect, because of the personal statement. I have filled out a personal statement, which is over 400 characters, as the objective states, and yet it still shows a 0/20.[image: Bug Image]

If I copy and paste my personal statement, directly from my profile, it turns out to be:[image: Word Count Pic]

Is this already a known issue, or is this a new problem? I could not find anything about this, searching both meta SE and doing a google search, but this is had no hits that matched well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Personal Statement" appears at the top of the profile. Yours is empty at the moment. The field you do have populated is actually the "Background" field.

You can add a Personal Statement by editing your profile and looking for the "Start one now" link toward the top. It'll appear as follows:
[image: screenshot of top of profile page, showing the explanatory text for Personal Statement field]

Comment: Thank you! I feel a bit stupid, but this completely clears up the problem :)

Comment: No problem. It's fair to say that's not the clearest part of the interface :)